# Do not process HTML as Markdown but keep definition lists

Tags: pandoc

I like the definition list syntax in Pandoc. I also have some raw HTML that is put into my document.

I don't want the HTML to be parsed as Markdown. I tried `--strict` to force Pandoc to ignore the HTML. This works but unfortunately this turns off the definition list feature. I could use HTML to write my DL but that is tedious. (The HTML comes from another source and should be left untouched.)

Are there any configuration options that give me more granularity over this?

(see [raw html](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-html) section in the manual and the [definition list](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#definition-lists) section. They both talk about how `--strict` disables them.)

Answer (score 3):

In the development version of pandoc, you can enable and disable pandoc extensions piecemeal, so for example you can specify `-t markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks` to disable the extension for parsing markdown inside HTML blocks.

You'd need to install from source, which requires the Haskell Platform.  Instructions are [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc-1.10), or you can wait for the next release.